# duplicate symbols when importing c++ file

Tags: c++, iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a project in XCode that uses some C++ code (`openCV` to be exact). One of my files, `AdjustVC.mm` importing this file (it's called `image_processing.mm`). Everything works fine. But when I import `image_processing.mm` in another file, `TestVC.mm`, I get errors:

```
ld: 14 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7
```

Comment: Why are you importing a ".mm" file? You should always import Header files only.
If you import an implementation twice, of course the linker will complain about it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's not a problem about your code base, `ld` is the tool for the linking phase, most likely you are using your libraries in the wrong way.

you should add more details about the libraries involved in your project or just verify them.

Comment: this is not helpful at all